# Recorrer un array desde controlador en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

buenas estoy comenzando con php y codeigniter, tengo el siguiente problema estoy recorriendo un array desde mi modelo, que es el resultado de una consulta, como puedo leer uno por uno mis registros en el controlador?

```html
function getClientes(){
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      if($query->num_rows()>0){
       $i=0;
  foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $img[$i]['id'] = $row->id;
            $img[$i]['nombre'] = $row->nombre;
            $img[$i]['ubicacion'] = $row->ubicacion;
            $img[$i]['telefono'] = $row->telefono;
            $i++;
        }
        return $img;
   }

 }
```

Comment: Que es lo que deseas lograr? Explica un poca mas para poderte ayudar

Comment: bueno asiendo un print_r al array que retorna la funcion en mi modelo.. obtengo lo siguiente Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [nombre] => jose [ubicacion] => av.cantar [telefono] => 567456 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [nombre] => juan [ubicacion] => alamos [telefono] => 342346 ), quiero saber como puedo desde mi controlador acceder solo a los datos de mi primera pocision es decir [0]

Comment: Ese print_r donde lo haces en el modelo o controler?

Comment: en  mi controlador

Comment: Lo que yo hago es retornar toda la consulta y ya en el controlador hago el foreach el cual tu estas haciendo en el modelo. No tengo muy claro lo que deseas hacer pero voy a escribir una respuesta espero que sea lo que tu necesitas

Answer (score 2):

Como te comento aun no tengo muy claro lo que deseas hacer pero espero te pueda ayudar, igual y si añades un poco de mas información te pueda ayudar en tu problema.

Model:

```
function getClientes(){
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query;
      }

    }
```

Controlador:

```
function procesaCliente(){
    $getClientes = $this->myModel->getClientes();
    foreach ($getClientes->result() as $row){
        $id = $row->id;
        $nombre = $row->nombre;
        $ubicacion = $row->ubicacion;
        $telefono = $row->telefono;
    }
}
```

Lo que hago es en la función del modelo retornar todo el objeto `$query` para en el controlador asignar el metodo del modelo a una variable en el controlador para poder procesar el arreglo que te devuelva la función.

En tu caso podrias asigar la función a una variable de la siguiente manera:

```
$getClientes = $this->myModel->getClientes();
```

Al tratar de obtener el indice asi:

```
$getClientes[0]['id']
```

Edición 1:

Lo que quieres es recorrer todo el array en la vista realizas lo siguiente en tu controlador:

```
function procesaCliente(){
    $getClientes = $this->myModel->getClientes();
    //Paso el array completo a la vista.
    $this->load->view('vista', $getClientes);
}
```

Y en la vista recorres el array de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($getClientes->result() as $row){
    $id = $row->id;
    $nombre = $row->nombre;
    $ubicacion = $row->ubicacion;
    $telefono = $row->telefono;
}
```

Comment: al usar esta forma como puedo pasarla a la vista, segui los pasos pero solo me muestra un resultado, y no el array completo

Comment: $getClientes del controlador lo pasas a la vista y haces el foreach en tu vista. Corrijo la respuesta y pruebas

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu conocimiento J.Castro